Dears i run it to ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [372478, 18583]
rs i run it to  Value Error: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [372478, 18583]  i test my model(X1), which is differetnt CSV file than i used on training trained my model(X) and when am tryaing to see the classifcation reualt it jupitor throws
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [372478, 18583]
the sahpe of my data ia as follows
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
(1489909, 31)
(372478, 31)
(1489909,)
(372478,)
print(X1.shape)----------> this is the CSV testing data which is d/t csv than X for traing
(18583, 31)
